# Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer returns memory access violation

Tags: c#, windows, system-calls

I'm trying to use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` to execute a `LdrLoadDll`'s syscall stub that I get from disk using my code, the code uses `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and later changed the memory protection changed into RWX(this is where the syscall stub from the disk lives). The defined syscall stub size in my code is 23 bytes. And this is the code that I use when I want to use the pointer to the allocated memory containing the syscall stub

```
// pLdrLoadDll contains the pointer to the allocated memory containing the syscall stub
// LdrLoadDllDelegate is my delegate for LdrLoadDll
Delegate funcDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pLdrLoadDll, typeof(LdrLoadDllDelegate));
NativeDeclarations.NTSTATUS retValue =  (NativeDeclarations.NTSTATUS)funcDelegate.DynamicInvoke(funcargs);
```

The code returns memory Access Violation when this line get executed

```
Delegate funcDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pLdrLoadDll, typeof(LdrLoadDllDelegate));
```

And I try to use other methods, like this one, and it returns the same error.

```
LdrLoadDllDelegate fSyscallLdrLoadDll = (LdrLoadDllDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pLdrLoadDll, typeof(LdrLoadDllDelegate));
```

I use the same function to get other syscall stubs and it works just fine using both of the these methods. I also try to use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` to execute `LdrLoadDll` but from the in-memory ntdll and it works fine. This is the only function that I test that doesn't work for my syscall stub extractor function.  I literally don't know why it throws out that error.

This is the code I use for extracting syscall stub from disk

```
public const int SYSCALL_STUB_SIZE = 23;
public static IntPtr GetSyscallStub(string FuncName) {
    IntPtr output = IntPtr.Zero;
    // get NTDLL full path
    string NTDLLFullPath;
    try{ NTDLLFullPath = (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>().Where(x => "ntdll.dll".Equals(Path.GetFileName(x.FileName), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault().FileName); }catch{ NTDLLFullPath = null; }
    if (NTDLLFullPath != null) {
        // allocate and copy original DLL to unmanaged memory
        byte[] NTDLLBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(NTDLLFullPath);
        IntPtr pNTDLLBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(NTDLLBytes.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(NTDLLBytes, 0, pNTDLLBytes, NTDLLBytes.Length);
        PEReader NTDLL = new PEReader(NTDLLBytes);
        int RegionSize = NTDLL.Is32BitHeader ? (int)NTDLL.OptionalHeader32.SizeOfImage : (int)NTDLL.OptionalHeader64.SizeOfImage;
        int SizeOfHeaders = NTDLL.Is32BitHeader ? (int)NTDLL.OptionalHeader32.SizeOfHeaders : (int)NTDLL.OptionalHeader64.SizeOfHeaders;
        IntPtr pNTDLLImage = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(RegionSize);
        // copying image header
        Marshal.Copy(NTDLLBytes, 0, pNTDLLImage, SizeOfHeaders);
        // copying sections
        for (int i = 0; i < NTDLL.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
            IntPtr pVASectionBase = (IntPtr)((UInt64)pNTDLLImage + NTDLL.ImageSectionHeaders[i].VirtualAddress);
            Marshal.Copy(NTDLLBytes, NTDLL.ImageSectionHeaders[i].PointerToRawData, pVASectionBase, (int)NTDLL.ImageSectionHeaders[i].SizeOfRawData);
        }
        // allocate unmanaged memory for the syscall stub
        IntPtr pSyscallStub = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SYSCALL_STUB_SIZE); // dont forget to change it to RX later
        // get pointer to function
        IntPtr pFunc = GetExportAddress(pNTDLLImage, FuncName);
        // copy from the function pointer to the allocated memory for syscall stub
        byte[] bSyscallStub = new byte[SYSCALL_STUB_SIZE];
        Marshal.Copy(pFunc, bSyscallStub, 0, SYSCALL_STUB_SIZE);
        Marshal.Copy(bSyscallStub, 0, pSyscallStub, SYSCALL_STUB_SIZE);
        // change syscall stub memory to RWX,using RX crashes the process,dont ask me why
        uint oldProtect;
        VirtualProtect(pSyscallStub, (UIntPtr)SYSCALL_STUB_SIZE, 0x40, out oldProtect);
        // free temporary allocations
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNTDLLBytes);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNTDLLImage);
        output = pSyscallStub;
        return output;
    }else {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to get NTDLL path.");
        return output;
    }
}
```

*GetExportAddress = GetProcAddress

I test the code on Windows 10 v20H2 using the built-in CSC as the compiler. To clear it out, I'm learning about AV/EDR Defense Evasion, cause that I use syscall stubs instead of P/Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of debugging on ntdll.dll, it turns out that LdrLoadDll doesn't use a normal syscall stub, cause it's a combination of multiple syscalls. the access violation error is caused by the syscall stub is not complete, cause it's size is not like a normal syscall stub.